# Errors: "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit" and "cannot open source file"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang++

I am getting the following errors after setting up C++ on VS Code and running starter code.

OS: MacOS Ventura 13.1 (Intel)
Editor: VS Code.
Compiler: clang++ (default)

`#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit`

`cannot open source file "tr1/cwchar" (dependency of "iostream")`

Below are my config files (c_cpp_properties, tasks, launch)

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    
        "env": {
          "myDefaultIncludePath": ["${workspaceFolder}", "${workspaceFolder}/include"],
          "myCompilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/clang++"
        },
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/tr1",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
  }
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: clang++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

The c++ code builds and runs. The error however persists. Anything regarding C++ installation might help.

PS: This is my first time setting up C++.

Comment: Why are you trying to point your brew clang to your brew gcc include path? And why are you referencing two different locations of clang++? Macs don't need to specify libc++, it's the default. Refer yourself to [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac). It is entirely possible that you'll have to nuke whatever you did to arrive these config files and start from scratch. Getting a C++ environment set up is not trivial.

Comment: If you don't want to do all that, just learn XCode instead. It's a decent IDE and actually comes with "batteries included."